# C# Web services cannot connect to database for stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, web-services, stored-procedures

I have C# web services which connect to a database server. The issue is that the services can execute one stored procedure properly, but it fails to connect to the database server for other stored procedure. The connection string is correct, as 1 stored procedure is getting executed, but I cannot understand why the connection would not be established for the other stored procedures on the same database.

Please share some ideas for me to find the solution.

Comment: A connection must be established before the stored procedure is executed and the proc to be executed is unknown at that point. Perhaps the connection is not being initialized as expected for the other procs. It might help if you post the error and some code.

Comment: Do you have a SqlException? What is the details?

Comment: Without code and the actual exception, otherwise no one has any idea what you are actually doing.